# Find the x minimal values in a distance matrix in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have computed a distance matrix between patches of ancient forests and recent forests in PostgresSQL thank to the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE MatDist as (
SELECT
  a.id a,
  b.id b ,
  st_distance(a.geom, b.geom) dist
FROM public.bvi_foret a, public.bvi_foret b
WHERE a.id != b.id AND a.ANC_FOR != b.ANC_FOR
)
```

and it works perfectly.

I want now to select the 5 pairs ancient forests (a)/recent forest (b) presenting the minimal distance between them.

So I started working with R, and I can find the unique pair presenting the minim distance, thanks to the following code:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[ , .SD[which.min(dist)], by = a]
```

But how can I compute the 5 first pairs? It's probably easy, with a for loop or an apply function in R, but I can't find it...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: see `?order` or `?sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM MatDistMat
ORDER BY dist
LIMIT 5;
```

> *Thanks for your answer, but I need the 5 first pairs FA/FR for each patch of ancient forest.*

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY dist ASC) as rn
     FROM MatDistMat) sub
WHERE sub.rn <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need the 5 first pairs FA/FR for each patch of ancient forest... I can compute the distance matrix with the min dist between FA and FR, but how for the 5 first min dist?CREATE TABLE MatDist as (
with t as (
    SELECT
      a.id a,
      b.id b ,
      st_distance(a.geom, b.geom) dist
    FROM public.bvi_foret a, public.bvi_foret b
    WHERE a.id != b.id AND a.ANC_FOR != b.ANC_FOR
),
    t1 as (
   SELECT a, min(t.dist) dist_min
   FROM t
   GROUP BY a
)
select t1.a, t.b, dist_min
from t1 left join t on t1.a = t.a and t1.dist_min = t.dist
)